# Почему сайт криво отображается в internet explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, html, javascript, css

Подскажите, что я не так сделал (делал по шаблону)? Все обозреватели нормально отображают, кроме IE. [Ссылка](http://212.98.168.50/~liderstr/).

Comment: Почему сайт криво отображается в <b>internet explorer</b>?<br>
Ответ таиться в вашем вопросе ^^

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что ссылка на сайт битая.

Answer (score 1):

У вас в head идет перечисление ссылок:

link rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" type="text/css" href="./files/reset.css" 
и т.д.

И все они "тянут" данные из папки files

Кроме одной:

[if lte IE 6] link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main-msie.css" /![endif]

Но у вас на сайте такого файла ни по адресу http://212.98.168.50/~liderstr/files/main-msie.css, ни по адресу http://212.98.168.50/~liderstr/css/main-msie.css нет такого файла.

Может, когда переносили шаблон, забыли перенести и перепрописать новый адрес?

Answer (score 0):

after не работает в ие, без размеров. На блок cols-in нужнно навесить еще width:100%. Убрать боковые паддинги, и поставить отступы на внутренние блоки в виде марджинов вот на эти content и aside
И сайт в ие7 будет нормальным.

Answer (score -1):

Некоторые css коды,internet explorer к сожалению не понимают,погугли ,типо css баги интернет експлоер.